# Identity Management for UNIX Password synchronisation gives warning

Tags: active-directory, sssd

I installed "Identity Management for UNIX" on win 2008 r2 active directory. I did this because I wanted to have the unix attributes, so I can link linux computers via ldap to the active directory. I followed [this tutorial](http://vaurent.com/red-hat-linux-active-directory-integration/), which worked fine. But ever since I get the warning

```
Password propagation is not done. Either default encryption key is configured or no UNIX hosts configured to propagate password
```

in my active directory. It is true that password propagation is not done, the passwords are all in active directory. No hosts are configured to propagate passwords. As far as I understand, all password related activities are delegated to active directory directly, sssd does only some caching while the machine is offline.

Can I tell AD that it is fine the way it is (is it? I think so, but am not sure), or did I miss some configuration on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need the password synchronization functionality you could, either remove the "Password Synchronization" role service using the Server Manager GUI, or from a PowerShell w/ an `Import-Module Servermanager` already run execute the `Remove-WindowsFeature ADDS-Password-Sync` command. (Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725709.aspx)

You'll need to restart the computer for the change to "take", in either case.